# Showing that if $\sum a_n,a_n\ge 0$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac {1}{n^2a_n}$ diverges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Showing that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac {1}{n^2a_n}$ diverges if  $\sum a_n,a_n\ge 0$ converges.

Since $\sum a_n$ converges, there exists $N$ such that for any $m\gt N$, the following holds:
$$a_{m+1}+a_{m+2}+\cdots+a_{2m}<\frac 12$$

By AM$\ge$ HM, $$\frac{\sum_{n=m+1}^{2m}a_n}{m}\ge \frac m{\sum_{n=m+1}^{2m}\frac 1{a_n} }\implies \frac 1{m^2}\sum_{n=m+1}^{2m}\frac 1{a_n}\ge \frac 1{\sum_{n=m+1}^{2m}a_n}\gt2. \tag 1$$

Let $S_n:=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac {1}{j^2a_j}$

$$|S_{2m}-S_m|\ge \frac 1{4m^2}\sum_{n=m+1}^{2m}\frac 1{a_n}\gt \frac 12,$$ (by $(1)$).

It follows that $\lim S_n$ doesn't exist.

Is my proof correct? Thanks.

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: In some places you wrote $a_n$ instead of $\frac{1}{a_n}$. E.g., in the second half of $(1)$ or the last displayed equation.

Comment: @Gary: Fixed. Thanks for the review. :)

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Thanks for the review. :)

Comment: I want to know if the claim, that if $\Sigma a_n$ converges, there is an $n$ beyond which all $a_n < \frac{1}{n}$ is true. This claim should be true in my view...If so, the result follows.  Thank you.

Comment: @sku, I think it is true. If $a_n>\frac1n$ for big $n$, then $\sum a_n$ diverges.

Comment: @xpaul That is what I think. I have never seen it said. With that property, this result quickly follows. Thank you

Comment: @sku: what if $a_n=\frac 1{n^3}$ if n is not a perfect cube and $a_n=\frac 1{n^{3/2}}$ if $n$ is a perfect cube? The example is inspired by suggestions to me in the chat.

Comment: @Koro I believe any $\Sigma \frac{1}{n^{k}a_n}$ is convergent as long as $k > 2$  and with the given condition. For your specific question $\Sigma 1/n^j$ is convergent for $j > 1$.

Comment: @sku: For the $a_n$ stated in my last comment, it may be noted that while $\sum a_n$ converges but there is no n beyond which all $a_n<1/n$.

Comment: @koro both $1/n^3$ and $\frac 1{n^{3/2}}$ are less than $1/n$

Comment: @sku: oops, please consider $a_n=\frac 1{n^{2/3}}$ when n is a perfect cube.

Answer (score 12):

Firstly, in your question if $a_n = 0$ for any $n$, then $\sum\frac {1}{n^2a_n}$ is ill-defined. Therefore, we must have $a_n>0$ for all $n$, and so also $\frac {1}{n^2a_n}>0$ for all $n$.

**My approach:**

Suppose $a_n,b_n > 0,\ $ $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ converge.

For all $n$ we have: $ \sqrt{a_n b_n} \leq \max\{a_n,b_n\}<a_n+b_n.$

Therefore, $ \sum\sqrt{a_n b_n} < \sum a_n+b_n$, which converges, since $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ converge.

Therefore $ \sum\sqrt{a_n b_n} $ converges. $\quad (1)$

Now suppose by way of contradiction that  $\sum \frac {1}{n^2a_n}$ converges.

Then, setting $b_n = \frac {1}{n^2a_n}$ in $(1)$ gives:

$\sum\sqrt{a_n \frac {1}{n^2a_n} }, $ which we know diverges, a contradiction.

Comment: That's very nice, thanks. :)

Comment: Another way of stating essentially the same proof: if you suppose $\sum \frac{1}{n^2 a_n}$ converges, then the sequences $(\sqrt{a_n})_{n=1}^\infty$ and $(\frac{1}{n \sqrt{a_n}})_{n=1}^\infty$ would both be in $\ell^2$, so by Cauchy-Schwarz you would have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{a_n} \cdot \frac{1}{n \sqrt{a_n}}$ is finite, again giving a contradiction.

Answer (score 8):

Your proof looks correct. In as much as the arithmetic-harmonic mean inequality is a particular case of Jensen's inequality, I had proven this as follows:

Jensen's Inequality says
$$
\frac1n\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac1{a_k}\ge\left(\frac1n\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}a_k\right)^{-1}\tag1
$$
Therefore,
$$
\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac1{k^2a_k}\ge\frac1{4n^2}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac1{a_k}\ge\left(4\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}a_k\right)^{-1}\tag2
$$
Since $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ converges, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{2n}a_k=0$. Thus, $(2)$ shows that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2a_k}$ diverges since the right side tends to $\infty$, not $0$.

Comment: I didn't know that AM$\ge HM$ is a special case of Jensen's inequality. Thank you very much. :-)

Comment: Indeed; the reciprocal of $(1)$, which is Jensen applied to $\frac1x$, is $AM\ge HM$.

Answer (score 3):

Another rather immediate approach is to use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$H_N^2:=\left(\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n}\right)^2=\left(\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{na_n^{\frac{1}{2}}}a_n^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)^2\leq \left(\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n^2a_n}\right)\left(\sum_{n=1}^Na_n\right).$$
Since $\lim_{N\to \infty} H_N = +\infty$, at least one of the factors on the right must diverge as well: since the latter factor does not diverge (by assumption), the former does.